# Wxpython doubling up underscore characters in Menu event.GetLabel()

Tags: python, wxpython

I load a menu with filenames from which the user will be able to choose from.
If the file name contains an underscore character (_), the

`event.GetEventObject().GetLabel(event.GetId())`

returns a value where any underscore character (_) is doubled up.
So a file name of `a_file.txt` becomes `a__file.txt`
I can get around the problem by using

`event.GetEventObject().MenuItems[event.GetId()].GetLabel()`

but not only do I not know if there are any repercussions of using this but
I don't particularly want to trawl through 1000's of lines of code hunting
for instances of this strange issue.
Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour and how to avoid it?

The demonstration code below illustrates the problem and the work around.
The tests are for a normal file name, a file name with spaces and a file name
with an underscore.

```
import wx

class MenuProblem(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.frame=wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
#        self.statusbar = wx.StatusBar(self-1)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText("Demonstration of wxPython")
        menu1 = wx.Menu()
        menu_item_1 = menu1.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&File")
        menu_item_2 = menu1.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Exit...")

    #Build a list of things via another function or just a declaration
        self.list_of_things = ["afilename.txt", "another filename.txt", "problem_filename.txt"]
        list_used = wx.Menu()
        thing_count = 0

        for thing in self.list_of_things:
            t1 = wx.MenuItem(list_used, thing_count, thing)
            list_used.AppendItem(t1)
            thing_count +=1

        thing_end = wx.MenuItem(list_used,199,'End of List')
        list_used.AppendItem(thing_end)

        menu1.AppendMenu(wx.ID_FILE,'&Problem Demo',list_used)
        menu1.SetHelpString(wx.ID_FILE, 'Click problem_filename.txt to see the doubling of underscore')

        self.menubar.Append(menu1, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)
    # Create bindings for the Thing list
        i_count = 0
        for i in self.list_of_things:
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnThingOpen, id=i_count)
            i_count = i_count + 1
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnThingEnd, id=199)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnClose, id=wx.ID_EXIT)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnThingOpen(self, event):
        id_selected = event.GetId()
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        print "Option        :", id_selected
        print "Label returned:", obj.GetLabel(id_selected)
        print "Now get the label in another way"
        print "Label returned:", obj.MenuItems[id_selected].GetLabel()
        print "From the range:"
        for i in range(obj.MenuItemCount):
            print "\t\t", obj.MenuItems[i].GetLabel()
        print "."*50

    def OnThingEnd(self, event):
        id_selected = event.GetId()
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        print "Option         :", id_selected
        print "Label returned :",obj.GetLabel(id_selected)
        print "Enabled", obj.IsEnabled(id_selected)
        print obj.MenuItemCount
        for i in range(obj.MenuItemCount):
            print obj.MenuItems[i].GetLabel()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    MC=MenuProblem(parent=None, id=-1)
    app.MainLoop()
```

EDIT:
It would seem that this is a bug in wxpython 2.8 (on Linux, perhaps other platforms) as the problem does not manifest itself using wxpython 3.0 on Windows. Information courtesy of @pss who tested the code for me.
The result being that I have indeed trawled through my code and used the work-around as detailed above.

Comment: Hey, I can't reproduce the problem. I am using Win 7 with python 2.7 and wxPython 3.0 . I executed your code then I selected the menu option and selected all the file names one by one. I got the correct results in the console window. The value of the label was same as the value returned from the label! Am I missing something? Here are the results: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4117/qo829pmv_png.htm

Comment: @pss No I don't think that you are missing something, I would guess that they have fixed the bug in wxpython 3.0. I am using 2.8 on Linux. Still, thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: If that fixes your problem then please post it as an answer and accept it. This will be helpful to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my original edit to the question, the fault seems to be a very old one as discussed on trac.wxwidgets.org ticket numbers #338, #9062, and #9055 and is related to the underscore (_) character being used as the escape character for GTK+. This form of error might exist on Windows as well but the errant character on Windows would not be the underscore but an ampersand (&) i.e. under Windows a file name such as a&filename.txt could be returned as afilename.txt as it would drop the ampersand completely (I'm not 100% sure of this see the code)
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/changeset/9055/svn-wx

So as @pss tested on the Windows platform, the issue may not be a simple bug that has been fixed but the result of a issue between wxpython/wxwidgets and the graphical platform that is being used.
One work-around should you come across this problem was detailed in the original question and works:

```
event.GetEventObject().MenuItems[event.GetId()].GetLabel()
```

or as stated in the code block more long-windedly:

```
id_selected = event.GetId()
obj = event.GetEventObject()
print "Label returned:", obj.MenuItems[id_selected].GetLabel()
```

Comment: @pss Any chance that you could test my supposition that the & rather than the _ character could cause a similar problem on Windows? I'd do it myself but I do not have access to a Windows machine.